# How can I highlight string found with :contains

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight matching text thats found with :contains.

I have tried:

```
$("ul#my_list").children('li:icontains("'+q+'")').each(function() {
            var newText = $(this).html().replace(q, "<span class='highlight_text'></span>");
            $(this).html(newText);
        });
```

this breaks the string

```
$("ul#my_list").children('li:icontains("'+q+'")').each(function(){
            var content = "Content1";
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(content,"<span class='highlight_text'>"+content+"</span>")
        });
```

this one does'nt break but only highlights the first character found

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6r1q9rx2/

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6r1q9rx2/1/

Comment: Is your fiddle correct? It has no css and javascript code is different from what you post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out: http://jsfiddle.net/6r1q9rx2/3/.

Your issue is that you don't strip out your inserted highlight spans before checking for matching text after the first keypress.

See:

```
jQuery.expr.filters.icontains = function(elem, i, m) {
    return (elem.innerText || elem.textContent || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
$(function() {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
        var q = $(this).val();

        //hide all items
        $("ul#my_list").children("li").hide();
        $("ul#my_list").children('li:icontains("'+q+'")').show();
        /*$("ul#my_list").children('li:icontains("'+q+'")').each(function() {
            var newText = $(this).html().replace(q, "<span class='highlight_text'></span>");
            $(this).html(newText);
        });*/
        $("ul#my_list").children('li').each(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).text());
        });
        $("ul#my_list").children('li:icontains("'+q+'")').each(function(){
            var content = q;
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(content,"<span class='highlight_text'>"+content+"</span>")
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: works like I want it to - and thank you for explaining the issue. will accept in ~3 mins

Comment: just fyi the matching is not longer case insensitive, any idea why?